# Moving Files Between S3 Buckets with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Is there an easy way to move files between two different buckets wiht laravel?

I'm dealing with large (4-5GB) files and I need to move about 50 of them from one bucket to another.

It looks like I would need to download them all then upload them with an artisan command.

Here's where I am now...

```php
    public function handle()
    {
        $files = Storage::disk('s3_old')->files();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileName = explode('/', $file)[1];
            $localPath = 'storage/app/tmp/'. $filename;
            $oldFile = Storage::disk('s3_old')->get($file);
            Storage::copy($oldFile, $localPath);

            $newLocation = Storage::disk('s3');

            $newLocation->put($localPath);
        }
    }
```

I don't expect to have to do this again, but I don't want to burn through transfer if I don't have to.

Comment: Yes, you have to download and upload. Spin up an EC2 instance in the same region as one or both buckets and run it from there to minimize network cost and maximize throughput. You can probably just use the AWS CLI tools and skip having to write the code yourself.

Comment: The AWS S3 SDK has the [`copyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject) command for this use case. You can combine that with a [deleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#deleteobject) (or just do `Storage::delete` on the old object). You can't leverage `copyObject` via the `Storage` facade as far as I can tell